# "every" vs "each"?

Tags: determiners

Consider:

> The ten lucky winners will ................. receive $1,000.

A) every

B) each

The answer in the book is **each**. As far as I know, **every** and **each** are used before singular nouns. I cannot understand the grammatical structure of the sentence. The only thing that I can guess is that **each**, as oppose to **every**, is also pronoun but, I don't know how this would help!

---

**Note 1:** The book preview option is not available although the book can be found on the google books!

**Note 2:** I know **each** has different connotation from **every**; the former has one-by-one connotation, the latter has a collective connotation; the problem is about the grammar.

Comment: See: [“Each” — pronoun or adverb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116662/each-pronoun-or-adverb)

Comment: @MadWard So, why has **each** been used between **will** and **receive** ?

Comment: In your example, the word ***each*** could be placed after *winners, will,* or *$1000* with no change in meaning (though the *middle* one of those three is undoubtedly more common overall). This is an *adverbial* usage (meaning "apiece"), not adjectival (placed before the noun it modifies).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ten lucky winners will......receive $1,000.

Each and every are often similar in meaning.  The only difference is between their usage as follows:

First, you use each when there are two or more things in a group, whereas you use every when there are three or more things in a group.

Second, the usage of each gives stress to individual things in the group, whereas  every refers to  things in the group as a whole. For example, every student passed the test = All the students passed the test.

Third, each is used as a determinor, pronoun, or adverb, but every is only used as a determiner.

Each and every are only interchangeable to convey the same meaning when there are three or more things in a group, and we use them as a determiner, without considering the stress they indicate.

Look at the following sentences to find how every is used as a determiner, and each is used as a determiner, pronoun, and adverb:

Every lucky winner will receive $1,000. (determiner)

Every one of the ten lucky winners will receive $1,000.(determiner)

Each lucky winner will receive $1,000. (determiner)

Each of the ten lucky winners will receive $1000.(pronoun)

The ten lucky winners will each receive $1,000. (pronoun)

The ten lucky winners will receive $1,000 each. (adverb).

As 'each' as a pronoun fits in the blank space of the sentence presented by the OP, you cannot use the determiner every here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The interesting point is that **each** as an **adverb** doesn't exist in Macmillan and Cambridge dictionaries whereas it does in Merriam-Webster and Oxford. By the way, can you tell me why the pronoun can be placed between the auxiliary and the infinitive? I mean, **will** and **receive**.

Comment: I think to place each after a modal, auxiliary verb, or to be verb is normal.

Answer (score 4):

The syntactic difference (between the possible usage of *each* and *every*) is probably best demonstrated by examples.

> CORRECT: *There were five men. **Each** had a sword and a bow.*
>   CORRECT: *There were five men. **Each man** had a sword and a bow.*
>   CORRECT: *There were five men. **Each of them** had a sword and a bow.*
>   INCORRECT: *There were five men.* <del>***Every*** had a sword and a bow.</del>
>   FIXED: *There were five men. **Every man** had a sword and a bow*.
>   INCORRECT: *There were five men.* <del>***Every of them*** had a sword and a bow.</del>
>   FIXED: *There were five men. **Every one of them** had a sword and a bow*.
>
> CORRECT: *They **each** had a sword and a bow.*
>   CORRECT: ***Each of them*** had a sword and a bow.
>   INCORRECT: <del>*They **every** had a sword and a bow.*</del>
>   FIXED: ***Every one of them*** had a sword and a bow.
>
> CORRECT: *They could **each** choose to use a sword or a bow.*
>   CORRECT: ***Each of them*** could choose to use a sword or a bow.
>   INCORRECT: <del>*They could **every** choose to use a sword or a bow.*</del>
>   FIXED: ***Every one of them*** could choose to use a sword or a bow.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is well explained in *Solutions 2nd edition Intermediate Student's book*.

> ## Determiners
>
> *Each* and *Every* are followed by a singular countable noun.
>   *Each* is used when all the people or things it refers to are seen individually. *Every is used to refer to all the people or things*.
>
> ***Each*** egg is painted in different colours.
>      ***Every*** egg can be purchased for ten euros.

Comment: Both can be followed by other word class.

Answer (score 1):

‘Each’ and ‘every’ are two similar words with almost identical meanings and very similar uses.  This makes the difference in meanings of these words unclear and stumps a lot of English native speakers when they try to explain the differences.

This is because ‘each’ and ‘every’ appear to be the same when we first look at them.  Both words are used to talk about individuals in a group; which makes understanding when to use ‘each’ and when to use ‘every’ challenging.

We can usually change one for the other without changing the meaning of the sentence, but there are times when we must use one or the other.

Below is an example of when using ‘each’ or ‘every’ doesn’t affect the meaning of the sentences:

“Each boy grows up to be a man” and “Every boy grows up to be a man”.

These sentences have the same meaning, but ‘each’ focuses on the individual boys while ‘every’ focuses on the group of individual boys as a whole.  The sentences have a different connotation or feeling, about them, but they have the same meaning.

https://www.krisamerikos.com/blog/each-vs-every

Answer (score 0):

"Each" is used when addressing individual members of a group

> The ten lucky winners will **each** receive $1,000.
>   **Each** of the ten lucky winners will receive $1,000.

"Every" is used to describe members of a group (singular - winner)

> Every lucky winner will receive $1,000.

They can also be combined

> **Every** lucky winner will **each** receive $1,000.