# A repeated action: each/every

Tags: word-choice, determiners

> I swim every day/Monday.

But could I say:

> I swim each day/Monday.

PS: I know there are already questions like [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113614/every-vs-each-usage), but please, try to understand my question before marking it duplicate without asking me if the other one replies to my question. I already read the other page, but I ask here if I can use it **IN THE PRECISE EXAMPLES I HAVE GIVEN.**

(forced to emphasize a lot, because very often people here read only half of the question, and mark it as duplicate)

Comment: As can be established by comparing [*...to church **each / every** Sunday*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+church+every+Sunday%2Cto+church+each+Sunday&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20church%20every%20Sunday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20church%20each%20Sunday%3B%2Cc0), ***every*** is far more common in such contexts. But that doesn't mean ***each*** is "wrong".

Comment: We don't mark questions as duplicates when they match in every tiny detail. Rather, we mark them as duplicates when the basic question being asked is so very similar that the same answers apply with only minor changes, so that the correct understanding can be gained from those answers no matter which of the duplicate questions a reader starts from. Things like changing "Monday" to "Tuesday" are considered part of "understanding", and, at a somewhat deeper level, realizing that "day" and "part of the banana tree" can be exchanged in various cases is as well.

Comment: PERCE-NEIGE - I'm sorry if you didn't get what you wanted or expected from this site. But I would point out that your excessive capitalisation (in the question, and repeated in a comment) is inherently rude over and above the fact that you chose to needlessly insult the community here by suggesting we habitually fail to read questions fully. I'll also point out that not only did I answeryour question in my first comment - I'm also the only person as yet who has upvoted @SovereignSun's perfectly correct answer (whereas *you* haven't even bothered to do this yourself yet! :)

Answer (score 1):

The most common word is **"every"** but **"each"** is also correct. You won't hear **each** as often as **every** though.

So both forms are acceptable:

- I swim every Monday.
- I swim each Monday

However, to my non-native ear **each** sounds much better in the beginning of the sentence:

- Each Monday morning I go to the lake.
- Each day I see you visit that cafe.